# Which test double should be used for void method

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, junit4

I'm writing a JUnit test for a method containing the following:

```
if (p.toString().contains("abc")) {
  cCreds(p);
  refMgr();
  p = new Path(Utils.rmvTkn(p.toString()));
}
```

`cCreds(p);` and `refMgr();` call void methods. I'm not actually testing these methods but they do get called in the method I am testing so I have to deal with them in some way. I know I need some sort of test double but I'm not sure what. I assume its not with a `when().thenReturn();` as nothing is actually returned.

Can anybody advise?

**Edit**

I should also mention, `cCreds(p);` and `refMgr();` are also private.

Answer (score 2):

Mocking is not necessary the thing to do here.
As these methods :

```
cCreds(p);
refMgr();
```

make part of the class under test, you are not compelled to mock them.

Mocking `public` or `private` methods of the class under test is not very natural.
 
It makes generally tests more brittle and less clear.
Mockito provides `spy` concept to achieve it but it should be favored for legacy code.

In the actual implementation, what you should check is that the method returns or performs a side effect which is expected.
You don't show the whole code of the method, so it is hard to give a more specific pointer.

---

Note that if these methods :

```
cCreds(p);
refMgr();
```

rely some other classes that you need to mock to isolate the component under test, you could refactor your code to extract the method in the dependent classes.
You would invoke them in this way :

```
foo.cCreds(p);
bar.refMgr();
```

And you could so mock them easily.

Answer (score 1):

Use `doNothing()` API from Mockito to mock void methods

```
doNothing().when(mock).cCreds(p);
doNothing().when(mock).refMgr();
```

Source: http://www.baeldung.com/mockito-void-methods

Comment: Or, if your test flow calls for an exception or a side effect from a void method then you would use do`Throw()` or `doAnswer()`.

Comment: Yep, thanks for adding it, the source link has examples in it for them

Comment: It's hard to say for certain without seeing more of the OP's test case but I don't _think_ the OP needs to invoke `doNothing()` at all here. Unless the test flow calls for an exception or a side effect I think these calls can be ignored in the test: `cCreds(p); refMgr();`.